# Pre-image and invertible maps

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, inverse-function

I tried to solve the following.

> Let  $f:X_1\rightarrow X_2$ be a bijective map with inverse $g$. Show that for any subset $U$ of $X_1$, we have that $f(U)=g^{-1}(U)$.

$h\in g^{-1}(U)$ means that $h\in X_2$ and so due to bijectivity, there exists a unique $a\in X_1$ such that $f(a)=h \in g^{-1}(U)$, so $g(f(a))\in U$. As $g$ is the inverse of $f$, we have that $a\in U$ and therefore $f(a)\in U$.

Suppose $b\in f(U)$, that means that there exists a unique $c \in U$ such that $f(c)=b$. So $b\in f(U)\subseteq X_2$, $g(b)=c$, by definition of inverse. Hence $b\in g^{-1}(U)$.

Is the proof correct? May I have some feedback, please?

Comment: What do you know about inverse maps? (For example, if two maps are the same, do you know that their inverses are the same?)

Comment: @rogerl well, yes. They are the same map.

Comment: It seems to me that your proof assumes what you want to prove. The statement makes sense if $g^{-1}(U)$ is not the image of $U$ via the function $g^{-1}$ but only the set $\{y \in X_2 \mid g(y) \in U \}$. But then the claim "$h\in X_2$ and so due to bijectivity, there exists a unique $a\in X_1$" does not make sense (who is bijective? $g$? Why?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct, but it also follows immediately from $f = g^{-1}$.

Comment: I think there is a clash of notation here: in many proofs classes, $g^{-1}$ denotes both the inverse function, and the inverse image of a set. These are not the same in general, and OP is trying to prove that they coincide when $f$ is bijective.

Comment: True, I mean the inverse function, what I maybe should have added is that if two functions are equal then they induce the same functions on the power sets.